# Problem making request to server with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem making a request to a server 
My simple code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/t/Desktop/App/etc.../jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/t/Desktop/App/etc.../json_parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/",{long:"29"},
    function(data){
    alert("data is"+ data.place[0].pk);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not get a "GET /search/?long=29 HTTP/1.1" . 
I always get a "OPTIONS /search/?long=30 HTTP/1.1"
Also when i check it with Firebug it says 0 requests.
Why is that?

Comment: What happens if you just alert the data? (not data.place[0].pk)

Comment: Nothing hapens since there the request is not done properly.

Answer (score 1):

it's because even though it's not TECHNICALLY cross domain, javascript thinks it is, and won't let you do it.